# Attendance marking/counting issue, Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image: See this screenshot]

I'm trying to create a customized attendance sheet in Google sheet. This is an attendance sheet for once a week classes. I added 5 columns in a month with a checkbox. now I need to do is, make an option to disable a column when that week's class did not happen/leave. otherwise, the total will counts that day as well and shows as an absent day of a student. so please help me resolve this issue.

here is my google sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hlTl5GiwOi2VVk04TtssgNnR62H795xyXo2n-3FiGtA/edit?usp=sharing

You can see the above sheet that, the graph showing the total present is 80%. but actually, what happened is, that student came all classes and his presence is 100%. that 5th week is class was leave(not happened). so please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: its not rly clear what do you want exactly... pls add some mocking data and desired output of your likenings

Comment: @player0  please check this screenshot... I added details of problem also... hope now you can understand.  ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccdYL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- checkbox **can't** have 3 states
- instead of 5 checkboxes use 10 with logic 1/0 for checked/unchecked
- eg. you will create 2 sets of checkboxes per each number

  [image]
- left checkbox is for `Present`
- right checkbox is for `Leave`
- if both unchecked = `Absent`
- if both checked = `Present`
- merge cells **B5** and **C5**
- paste formula in **B5** and drag to right

---

```
=IF(B4=1,"Present",
 IF(AND(B4=0, C4=1), "Present",
 "Absent"))
```

- [image: 0]
- then aggregate chart from **B5:K5**
- and if you wish you can play with conditional formatting and colors to hide 1st checkbox when 2nd is checked and vice versa. custom formula is: `=C4=1` and font color is custom: `#fffffd`

  [image: 0]
- ### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1l-mkUFNtPFIqwOHPy4ovB1V8OS_i5xicqklqVvpA4/edit#gid=40581279)